# How to perform revert in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, revert, intellij-plugin

There are many actions that has been done by plug-in or user. I want to revert them, How to revert the actions programmatically.

Comment: I have gotten pretty good mileage just by using UNDO.  How many actions are you dealing with here?

Comment: UNDO will revert the complete thing. but i am having some steps, want to revert them. Sometimes only some particular steps. how to do this. I am adding so many files step by steps. the number of files that is been added, not constant.

Comment: There is no API for reverting an arbitrary action performed in IntelliJ IDEA. If you want to revert a specific kind of action, please provide more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to revert the changes which are not necessarily on the top of the stack and there are lot of such changes. changes means adding a file, adding a method into the file, adding the dependency, removing the method..like that.